# Checkbox change event not firing when the validations are fired on the page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRecurringfeetype" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkRecurringfeetype_CheckedChanged" />
```

I am using `Page_ClientValidate()` to validate the fields on button click.

When i click on submit button on  my page, the required field validations gets fired for all the fields, after that when i check the checkbox first time, nothing happens at first time. When i again click on it, it fires the event. 
Please let me know what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are validating the form by using `Page_ClientValidate()` and this prevents the page to fire any asp.net controls event. Please remove the Page_ClientValidate() from client side and add the `(!Page.Isvalid) return;` on button click in cs file. I hope it may helps you.